# Reactor retry with new processor

Tags: java, reactor

I have list of messages and list of processors. I have to iterate processors to send messages. If processor return error on some messages, I have to go to next processor and send failed messages to him. But the problem is that processor return `Mono<MessageResult>`, so, I couldn't just save results to local variable, filter out successfull and then process failed.

```
public interface MessageProcessor {

  Flux<MessageResult> send(List<Message> messages);
}

public class Message {

  private final String text;
}

public class MessageResult {

  private final Message message;
  private final Boolean success;
}
```

Is there any way to create an elegant solution in this way?

```
public class MessageService {

  private final List<MessageProcessor> processors;

  public Flux<MessageResult> sendMessages(List<Message> messages) {

  }
}
```

I tried to create some kind of `MessageService` but I don't know how to iterate in messages to send in first processor and then in second in case that processor return `Mono`.

Comment: Interesting, but there's some details I don't understand. Do you want to process your messages one by one, or give them all in one go to your processor ? Also, do you want to retry with another processor if you've got an **empty** mono ?

Comment: @amanin i have to pass all messages to processor.
there won't be a situation when I will get an empty mono. I will always have a result.

Comment: Still unclear to me. You say processor returns Mono, but in the code you posted, processor returns **Flux**. Shouldn't the MessageProcessor interface only method be `Mono<MessageResult> send(Message message);` instead ?